# gmail html not working in mobile devices it ignores the media queries?

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive mailer which should work in gmail but when i check the mail in my gmail mobile app it doesn't work.... its like the media queries is being ignored by gmail.I have pasted the entire code below you can have a look at it. When i checked for responsive in my web browser emulator its working fine but in gmail app the media queries are being ignored.
               thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mailer</title>
    <style>
        .centertab {
            width: 650px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:480px) {

            .centertab,
            table,
            tb,
            th,
            tr {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            p {
                padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
            }

            td {
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                display: block !important;
                text-align: center;
            }

            img {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }

            .social {
                width: 30px !important;
                max-width: 30px !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }
              h1,
            h2,
            h3 {
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: darkgrey">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="centertab" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background-color: white; margin-top: 40px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Header with company logo -->
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <h1>Company Name</h1>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--Banner -->
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 650px">
                                        <img src="images/banner.jpeg">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <h2 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">Text title</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" style="background-color: aqua;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="images/1.jpeg" style="width: 300px;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.3; padding: 10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed convallis justo. Mauris egestas sed quam ultricies efficitur. Praesent pulvinar lorem quis ex lacinia, eu lacinia ipsum ornare. Proin hendrerit eros sed leo feugiat accumsan. Donec semper tincidunt interdum. Nullam non aliquet urna.Etiam efficitur velit id eros ullamcorper, vel elementum lorem scelerisque. </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" style="background-color: blanchedalmond;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 300px">
                                        <p style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.3; padding: 10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed convallis justo. Mauris egestas sed quam ultricies efficitur. Praesent pulvinar lorem quis ex lacinia, eu lacinia ipsum ornare. Proin hendrerit eros sed leo feugiat accumsan. Donec semper tincidunt interdum. Nullam non aliquet urna.Etiam efficitur velit id eros ullamcorper, vel elementum lorem scelerisque. </p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <img src="images/2.jpeg" style="width: 300px;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="background-image: url(images/banner2.jpeg); width: 100%; height: 210px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <h3 style="color: white"><span style="background-color: blue">Text With title</span></h3>
                                        <h3 style="color: white"><span style="background-color: red">Some Text</span></h3>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr class="socialicons">
                                    <td>
                                        <table width="200px">
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="images/fb.png" class="social" style="width: 30px;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="images/google.png" class="social" style="width: 30px;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="images/linkedin.png" class="social" style="width: 30px;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="images/twitter.png" class="social" style="width: 30px;">
                                    </td>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table width="300px">
                                <tr align="right">
                                    <td>Company Name</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

in advance

Comment: In the email code you must use inline css. maybe this can help you [https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/](https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/)

Answer (score 0):

Gmail or outlook doesnt support most codes. Like media querys. I think you dont need responsive for mailing. Because just you dont need man :)

In my opinion you can use just inline-css. don't use style tag. its best way to make html mailing.